# Highcharts stop auto-numbering in X-Axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts, char

I want to stop auto-numbering on X-Axis, Need to display 5 value fixed on x-Axis,

And Y-Axis has it may be 3 or 12 or 20 or 30 points etc. (inShort dynamically value, not equal to xAxis)

Please check following screenshot for this.

[image]

**Code content:-**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Highcharts Example</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    #container {
        width: 500px;
        height: 300px;
        margin: 0 auto
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    Highcharts.chart('container', {

        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },

        chart: {
            backgroundColor: 'white'
        },

        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },

        title: {
            text: '',
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            }
        },

        xAxis: {
            lineColor: '#000000',
            categories: ['17 Dec', '24 Dec', '31 Dec', '7 Jan', '14 Jan'],
            labels: {
                style: {
                    color: 'black'
                }
            }
        },

        yAxis: {
            gridLineColor: '#000000',
            title: {
                text: 'Weight (KG)'
            },
            labels: {
                style: {
                    color: 'black'
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Weight',
            data: [10, 40, 60, 30, 50, 20, 45, 41, 51, 53, 81, 70]
        }]
    });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is there anything that you want to show instead of these numbers (5, 6, 7...) or just to hide them?

Answer (score 0):

Use [slice()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp) to reduce to array length to 5

`data: data.slice(0, 5)`

```js
var data=[10, 40, 60, 30, 50, 20, 45, 41, 51, 53, 81, 70]
    Highcharts.chart('container', {

        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },

        chart: {
            backgroundColor: 'white'
        },

        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },

        title: {
            text: '',
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            }
        },

        xAxis: {
            lineColor: '#000000',
            categories: ['17 Dec', '24 Dec', '31 Dec', '7 Jan', '14 Jan'],
            labels: {
                style: {
                    color: 'black'
                }
            }
        },

        yAxis: {
            gridLineColor: '#000000',
            title: {
                text: 'Weight (KG)'
            },
            labels: {
                style: {
                    color: 'black'
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Weight',
            data: data.slice(0, 5)
        }]
    });
```

```css
#container {
 min-width: 310px;
 max-width: 800px;
 height: 400px;
 margin: 0 auto
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Hello Patat in your code has removed points, in your example xAxis has 5 label and 5 point displayed, But i want to display 12 points.

Comment: So you want to display as many  Y-Axis points with 5 points X-Axis

Comment: If the case is like that then follow https://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-time-series